# Why is there an offset between reprojection results of ArcGIS and QGIS from PSAD56 to WGS84?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system

I did a comparison of file system PSAD 56 to WGS 84 with arcgis and qgis and the difference is 8 m, why is the difference?

This is a points file (shape) and it is in UTM Zone 19S.

Comment: Are you trying to project between two different coordinate systems?

Comment: Can you provide more details about the procedure you used in each software in order to undertake your comparison, please?

Comment: I did a comparison of file system PSAD 56 to WGS 84 with arcgis and qgis and the difference is 8m, why is the difference?

Comment: This is a points file (shape) and it is in UTM Zone 19S

Comment: So much could be going wrong, Vanessa, that for anyone to provide good advice you must describe what you have done with each software, how you performed the comparison, and provide examples of the inputs and outputs.

Answer (score 1):

An offset of 8 metres is considered normal for PSAD56 datum. See [forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=984&t=204529](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=984&t=204529).

There are several transformation parameters available; QGIS and Arcgis might not use the same.

Comment: Vanessa, WGS 84 is a broad description of a CRS, can you include the EPSG no?